# podio , how to get count items per view?

Tags: podio

I use this function to get total items in a view:

$total_new_properties=PodioItem::get_count( $app_id,$view_id );
but it returns the total number of items in the app,not the total number of items from the view.
The sand box has an input for the view_id, but the function get_count receives only the app_id . Can get_count return total numbers of the view, or is there another way to get total number of the items in a view ?(but only the total, nothing else)

Answer (score 0):

Please use [get-view](https://developers.podio.com/doc/views/get-view-27450) method, and then use `[:groupings]['total']`

**Ruby** sample

```
view_id = <my view id>
bugs_view = Podio::View.find(view_id)
total_bugs_count = bugs_view[:groupings]['total']
```

Comment: In my response after calling PodioView::get( $view_id ),  grouping is empty , this is how is looks in the sand box: "grouping": {

  }

Comment: Please update your question with full example and response

Comment: I have also used the sandbox , entered the view_id there and the response, in the sandbox, had the gropping empty "grouping": { }  (the other information about the view is private and there is no point in displaing it)

Comment: there are 2 similar calls, one with app_id and another without app_id. I'm sure code sample that I've shared works well, because that's a copy/paste from working code. In order to understand why it's not working for you, I need to get more info

Comment: I have used the one from the link u provided me : $bugs_view = PodioView::get( $view_id );